# Simple way to split UTF16 string by NULL

Tags: java, string, utf-16

I'm extracting UTF16 strings from a byte array, the strings are separated by one or more NULL(U+0000), when I print the converted string, it trims the NULL automatically, the below example program outputs "WinWin"

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

class Ucs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {87, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 87, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0}; 
        String s = new String(b, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
        System.out.println(s);
    }   
}
```

but I want them separated like "Win Win", only if I split `s` by something. I know I can find the NULL character in a for loop, which is really nasty. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\00")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method called replaceAll(). It´s quite simple to use.

```
string.replaceAll("<the letter you want to replace>", "");
```

Mind though that this won´t really increase your performance if that´s what you are looking for.